# subdomain of wordpress keep redirecting to main domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

this is what I did and expect to clone a wp blog for development.

1. I created a sub domain in cpanel, says dev.myblog.com
2. I download a copy of db and then uploaded to the newly created db.
3. I changed the wp-config - db name etc..

but the problem is the sub domain keep redirecting to the main domain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create you should

1. export DB
2. change the URLs in db file

   1. open db file using Wordpad or any editor
   2. find `wp_options`
   3. then scroll down little bit, you find your old URL
   4. replace the old URL to new URL in complete file
   5. save the file.
3. import the file to the new DB
4. now run the new URL in browser

**Note: after this you must add the widget data and also update the permalinks**

Comment: the setting couldn't be save.. why?

Comment: the settings data is in serialized form so it will not remain save

Comment: so? even I try to apply new setting and click save and it doesn't take effect.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164831/migrating-widget-settings-in-wordpress

Answer (score 4):

simply add this to your wp-config file

```
define('WP_HOME','http://subdomain.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://subdomain.example.com');
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the site URL and home URL in your database (`wp_options` table).  You'll probably want to replace other mentions of your old URL too, such as in linked posts or the `guid`.

You say you use cPanel, so you should have access to phpMyAdmin.  If you go there, you can run this SQL (you'll need to replace the old and new URLs where appropriate):

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to change the siteurl entry inside of the wp_options table. Search for siteurl by field option_name.

Comment: I have replaced the siteurl and homeurl too but didn't work in my case too.Its redirected to main domain url evertime I hit the sudomain

Answer (score 1):

Change the site URL on the WP_OPTIONS table if it exists on DB if not
go to wp-config.php and add below two entries on the file.

```bash
define('WP_HOME','http://subdomain.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://subdomain.example.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

This might have been answered in a newer post/Q, but FWIW:
In addition to the proposed solution (the change of URLs inside the wp_options table), I need to modify the .htaccess file as well like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir[L]
```

Here's the WP support site where I found the code and further info:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work for me I first added the following to `wp-config` on the sub-domain:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://subdomain.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://subdomain.example.com');
```

The above still forwarded to the main site so I then opened the sub-domain's DB in phpMyadmin and updated the site URL under `wp-options`.

Once I did that it was forwarding correctly.